# Not having the page reload or being redirected if the login credentials are wrong - Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, login, redirect, messages, global-messages

On the login page, when the end-user enters a wrong password, the page gets refreshed and then returns the error massage, is there a way that I can have the error appears right away after entering the wrong credentials?

The main reason I need this is because of a pop-up login form that I have created, I would like to see if there are possibilities to make the error presents on the page after the user clicked on the "login button", instead of reloading the page, or redirecting to the login page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Magento 2.2

Comment: Magento does many validations are server side for registration, you would have to develop custom module if you want to do these validations at client end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload the page by default, you should write a custom module that use ajax request to validate username and password.